Guidance on Extracting Compliance Items from PDF documents by fine-tuning a LLM
Need some guidance on extracting large compliance items from raw PDF documents. I have csv with these compliance items and I want to fine-tune a LLM such that if it reads any new PDF documents it can firstly identify the compliance items and extract them.
I have seen LLMs used for NER but this kinds of falls into Named Phrase Recognition(NPR - don't know if an acronym like this exists).
The PDFs are servicing guides.
Examples of them can be seen from the following site: https://servicing-guide.fanniemae.com/
These are documents with lots of pages. They have compliance items inside them. I have a training document with these compliance documents.
Compliance Items:
Compliance items are varied in nature. They can range from

"The servicer must document in the mortgage loan servicing file the date that the COVID - related hardship began and the date of the insured loss event."
An incentive fee payment for an eligible short sale is disbursed as outlined in the following table  2. Fannie Mae reviews eligibility for the short sale incentive fee and makes the determination based on information provided by the servicer through Fannie Maeâ€™s servicing solutions system.

So, regex or anything is not suitable since there are various types of these items.
My goal is to train a LLM model on these compliance documents so that if I provide a new PDF it can predict/extract compliance items from it.
Can anyone guide me in which model will be better suited for this task, what tokenizers etc.

Yes, thats what I am saying, compliance items are varied in nature. What I have got are numerous compliance items that have extracted by a separate team and put in a csv. Hence regex doesn't work. Need a powerful model which can understand what a compliance is from the training set and then extract.

I understand and I am not questioning you. But this is the training dataset a separate team has provided to me. So based on that I have to train the model.
